# Replacing a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I've implemented the bottom navigation view in an activity which I use to navigate between fragments. Apparently, there is some strange behavior when switching between fragments. Whenever I log out of my app and log in with the a different account. Details of the former account are shown occasionally. This happens when I switch to the same fragment continuously. The database I'm using is realm, and all the data is usually cleared out on logout. I have verified. Whenever I logout, the activity with the fragments is destroyed using `finish()` So how is it that I'm getting fragments with data from the previous account. Are fragments left in the stack event after the parent activity is removed? The issue is really bothering because I can't really explain the cause. The code for replacing fragments is as follows:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            boolean initialSync = Preferences.getBoolean(MainActivity.this, "initialSync");
            if (!initialSync && item.getItemId() != R.id.navigation_logout) {
                InitialSyncFragment fragment = new InitialSyncFragment();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }

            getFirstName();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_grades:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new GradesFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_finances:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new FinancesFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_info:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new InfoFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_logout:
                    logout();
                    break;
            }
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
```